# Finding $\operatorname{rank} T$ where $T(u)=(u,v)w$

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $V=\mathbb{C}^{n \times n}$. Defining $T(u)=(u,v)w$ for $v,w\in V$, what is $\operatorname{rank} T$?

Thank you!

Comment: Assuming that $(\cdot,\cdot)$ denotes an inner product, $T(u)$ is a scalar multiple of $w$ for every $u$. So what is the range of $T$, and hence what is the rank of $T$?

Comment: @BranimirĆaćić: it is one! Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome, though you should be careful about one tiny technicality: if $v = 0$ or if $w = 0$, what happens?

Comment: @BranimirĆaćić: wild guess, and please excuse me, in that case then rank of T is as dim V?

Comment: Well, if $v = 0$ or $w = 0$, what is $T(u)$ for any $u$?

Comment: \mathrm{rank} T and \operatorame{rank} T yield results that look different from each other.  See my edit.

Comment: @BranimirĆaćić Please consider converting your comment into an answer, so that this question gets removed from the [unanswered tab](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/3138). If you do so, it is helpful to post it to [this chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9141) to make people aware of it (and attract some upvotes). For further reading upon the issue of too many unanswered questions, see [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/143113), [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/1148) or [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/9868).

Comment: @JulianKuelshammer Done and done.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that $(\cdot,\cdot)$ denotes an inner product, $T(u)$ is a scalar multiple of $w$ for every $u$. So, what is the range of $T$, and hence, what is the rank of $T$? You do need to be careful, though, if $v=0$ or $w=0$; indeed, what is $T(u)$ for any $u$ in that case?